# Reading appsettings.json file settings is always null. How to do this in .NET 7 (the best way)?

Tags: .net-core, blazor-webassembly, appsettings, .net-7.0

I am switching a project from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 7, but, but I can't seem to get this to work. I thought the configuration was already built into the framework (using Blazor) and configuration data was already injected behind the scenes, so you could just access the `appsettings.json` file via

```
builder.Configuration.GetSection("MySection:MyParam").Value;
```

from within the `program.cs` class. It always returns null, so perhaps the `builder.Build()` needs to be called first (which usually does), but I need to get the data from the `.json` file before it's built in order to define services first. Not sure how to do this correctly.

The `program.cs` file contents:

```
using BlazorWASM;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;

namespace Company.WebApplication1;

public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
        builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
        builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

        string APIPath = builder.Configuration.GetSection("API:Path").Value; //this is coming up null

        builder.Services.AddSingleton(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(APIPath) });

        await builder.Build().RunAsync();
    }
}
```

And this is the `appsettings.json` file located in the `wwwroot` (default) folder:

```
{
      "API": {
        "Path": "https://api.somewebsite.com/"
      },
      "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost;Database=_CHANGE_ME;Trusted_Connection=True;"
      }
}
```

Any ideas? I know I'm doing something wrong, but there must be a hundred different ways to access the `appsettings.json` file, but, would like to see a best practices way (that actually works).

Answer (score 1):

I discovered, to my horror, that you can't read files from Blazor WASM. The only way to do this is to create a service and have it use httpclient to grab configuration data from a separate server.
While the app in question is currently hardcoded to use other APIs, it works fine for now, but if any of those other APi endpoints change (many are 3rd party), the user of the app will have to download a fresh copy of the app OR I need to make a public API whose URI is hardcoded into the app itself, then 3rd party API URIs can be changed quickly (via an upload of configuration settings every time the app starts).
When I think about it, this was a dumb question.

Answer (score 0):

> but I need to get the data from the .json file before it's built in order to define services first.

You can use [Options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/options) for that.
I would say you need some sort of its usage:

1. Create class for your settings.

   ```
        public class CustomSettings
        {
            public static string SectionName = nameof(CustomSettings);

            public string FirstService { get; set; }

            public string SecondService { get; set; }
        }
   ```
2. Add matching section to config file.

```
    {
      "CustomSettings": {
        "FirstService": "http://localhost:8090",
        "SecondService": "http://localhost:8091"
      }
    }
```

3. And bind it, using API of IConfiguration object:

```
 var settings = app.Configuration.GetSection(CustomSettings.SectionName)
                   .Get<CustomSettings>();
```

It should work. Cheers!

PS: In 3rd stage you you want to use `builder.Configuration...` instead of `app.Configuration`, it would also work.

Comment: I just found out that you cannot read appsettings.json from a web assembly blazor app (you can't read any files for that matter), so this isn't going to work. I think I need javascript to read the config, but need to start the app first, so it's a catch-22

Comment: Let me edit - i used other application template.

Comment: Yep, you are right, configuration is not read in blazor apps. Config is located on backend, but webassembly lives in browser runtime, so it just can't read.

Answer (score 0):

So long as you're setting up your S3 bucket to be public, you can still read anything that is in it, so I just read it.

I used an assumption you can change for your needs, but with the following code.

```
//Not the best assumption, but here we go
if (!builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress.Contains("localhost"))
{
    using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress);
    var jsonStream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync("/appsettings.json");
    builder.Configuration.AddJsonStream(jsonStream);
}
```

## Disclaimer

There are serious security implications here as S3 static sites are generally *public*, and you shouldn't store any secret info such as connection strings or passwords.

Your static site should use a 3rd party authentication service to connect to an API somewhere you maintain.